# Removing a nested document in mongo db using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am facing problems while removing a nested document in mongo db using mongoose. The schema looks like this

```
const iLevelPlanning = new mongoose.Schema({
    istep: String,
    maturity,
    milestone: [milestone],
    buildingPhase: [buildingPhase]
});

const planningOverview = new mongoose.Schema({
    brv: String,
    introduction: String,
    pl: String,
    iLevelPlanning: [iLevelPlanning],
    comment: [comment],
    modified: Date,
});
```

For debugging purposes, I tried 2 scenarios in the mongo shell

### Attempt 1

```
db.getCollection('planningOverview').updateOne({ _id: "62ecfcd1caae1e0000beb8ee" }, { $pull: { iLevelPlanning: { _id: "63172667f1242f000012b93f" } } })
```

### Attempt 2

```
db.getCollection('planningOverview').updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("62ecfcd1caae1e0000beb8ee") }, { $pull: { iLevelPlanning: { _id: ObjectId("63172667f1242f000012b93f") } } })
```

The first one did not work. But the second one worked.

Now I have to do this from my node application.

I tried something like this here also

### Attempt 3

```
getPlanningOverviewModel().updateOne({ _id: id}, { $pull: { iLevelPlanning: { _id: iLPId} } }).exec();
```

### Attempt 4

```
getPlanningOverviewModel().updateOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}, { $pull: { iLevelPlanning: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(iLPId) } } }).exec();
```

Of course, the first one did not work, however, the second code also not updating in the database.
It's not finding the matched objects.

And I have also imported mongoose  as well

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
```

Comment: What does this function do `getPlanningOverviewModel`?

Comment: ```export interface PlanningOverviewDoc extends PlanningOverview, mongoose.Document {}
export type PlanningOverviewDocDef = mongoose.DocumentDefinition<PlanningOverviewDoc>;

export const getPlanningOverviewModel = () =>
    getMongooseConnection(module).model<PlanningOverviewDoc>('PlanningOverview', planningOverview, 'planningOverview');``` This is not the problem because I am also doing all other operations like read, upsert everything using getPlanningOverviewModel(). And those are working fine